# Undefined avatar method from Carrierwave in RoR application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I get this error message:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `avatar=' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f87e4c304d8>):
  app/controllers/api/v1/user_controller.rb:10:in `upload'
```

Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_token_authenticatable

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader

  validates_presence_of   :avatar
  validates_integrity_of  :avatar
  validates_processing_of :avatar
end
```

Controller:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class UserController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]
      #before_filter :authenticate_user_from_token!

      def upload
        puts "here => " + params[:user][:email].to_s
        @user = User.where(email: params[:user][:email])
        @user.avatar = params[:user][:file]
        @user.save!
        p @user.avatar.url # => '/url/to/file.png'
        p @user.avatar.current_path # => 'path/to/file.png'
        p @user.avatar_identifier # => 'file.png'
      end
...
```

environment.rb:

```
# Load the Rails application.
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!
```

The AvatarUploader was generated and the avatar:string column was added to the users table through the migration execution. I am not sure what's wrong with it.

Extra info: I use Rails: 4.2.4, Ruby: 2.2.1

Many thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pretty informative. When you call `User.where(email: params[:user][:email])` you don't get a `User` object, you get an `ActiveRecord_Relation` object, wich can contain multiple `ActiveRecord` objects or be empty. To get a single `User` you want to use `find_by` instead of `where`, then you'll be able to get access to the avatar.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this information this solves this issue.